# How to send push notifications in progressive web app

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm using curl command to send push notification it works properly.Here is my curl command

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=GjO1y_hPm-xUdgnM25Ny4" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"dFWzS2cc7I0:APmREGNkRg8YKdlVp89vUVNTuEI0ygJ8TZ-7lhzs9wGek6nEiojzA-N2BC1dxbPpT1_VsTtM6kS9LLJ90bIK_xvt5Y2TTx6qB_GUsjYxGF3Ni4UBr7_H6NeVMIYmYPj7\"]}"
```

When i execute this command through command line notification delivered to user.I want to send notification on button click.how can i do that.

Comment: What is your server doing on `send_notification`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use asp.net c# to send notification on button click.here is my code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string RegArr = string.Empty;
RegArr = string.Join("\",\"", RegistrationID);      

string message = "some test message";
string tickerText = "example test GCM";
string contentTitle = "content title GCM";
 postData =
"{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + RegArr + "\" ], " +
"\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
"\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
"\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";

string response = SendGCMNotification("Api key", postData);
}
```

SendGCMNotification Function:-

```
private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
    {

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        //  CREATE REQUEST
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = false;
        Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
        Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        //
        //  SEND MESSAGE
        try
        {
            WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
            HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
            if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
            }
            else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
            }
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            Reader.Close();

            return responseLine;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return "error";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of APIs we need to check before we enable our button. Below is a brief overview of the steps given in [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) wherein sample codes can also be found:

> - We check that **showNotification** is available in the ServiceWorkerRegistration prototype. Without it we won’t be able to show a notification from our service worker when a push message is received.
> - We check what the current **Notification.permission** is to ensure it’s not “denied”. A denied permission means that you can’t show notifications until the user manually changes the permission in the browser.
> - To check if push messaging is supported we check that **PushManager** is available in the window object.
> - Finally, we used **pushManager.getSubscription()** to check whether we already have a subscription or not. If we do, we send the subscription details to our server to ensure we have the right information and set our UI to indicate that push messaging is already enabled or not. We’ll look at what details exist in the subscription object later in this article.

[Your first push notifications web app](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en) can also help you on how to properly implement Push Notifications to web applications.

Comment: i already go through the documentation provided by google on push notifications but i got issue on the time of making request to GCM to send a notification using XHR